# wget --warc-file gets only main page and robot pages?

Tags: wget, warc

I am trying to do a little project on a small-ish WARC file. I used this command:

```
[ ! -f course.warc.gz ] && wget -r -l 3 "https://www.ru.nl/datascience/" --delete-after --no-directories --warc-file="course" || echo Most likely, course.warc.gz already exists
```

First time I ran it, everything went fine, got over 150 pages worth, amazing. Now I wanted to redo it from scratch, so I deleted the file 'course.warc.gz'; problem is, when I run the same command now I get 3 pages: the one requested for, and two robot pages to boot. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

> Wget can follow links in HTML, [...] This is sometimes referred to as “recursive downloading.” While doing that, Wget respects the Robot Exclusion Standard (/robots.txt). ([wget manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Overview.html#Overview))

The [robots.txt](https://www.ru.nl/robots.txt) includes the following rule:

```
# Block alle andere spiders
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Difficult to answer whether what happened during the previous run of wget. Maybe the robots.txt changed?